# How to specify the corresponding line of a truth table in a formula?

Tags: propositional-calculus

How to specify the corresponding line of a truth table in a formula: 
$$p \to (\neg q \lor (q \to p))$$
$p$ evaluates to $F$ and $q$ evaluates to $T$.

I want to know the method followed to find this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking, how do you evaluate the truth value of the formula, at those values of its variables?

You substitute those values for the variables (or constant symbols $\bot, \top$ for false and true respectively. Finally you evaluate the constant atomic subformulas and then the resulting constant atomic subformulas, and so on, iterating until you've reduced to a single (symbol for a) truth value, $\bot$ or $\top$.

Given the assignment $(p=\bot, q=\top)$, given that the formula is of the form $p\to \dotsc$, it's immediately obvious that the formula evaluates to $\top$, because $\bot\to\dotsc$ is always true. But we'll go through the exercise of substituting and reducing:
$$\begin{align}
p \to (\neg q \lor (q \to p))[\bot/p][\top/q] &= \bot \to (\neg \top \lor (\top \to \bot)) \\
&= \bot \to (\bot \lor (\top \to \bot)) \\
&= \bot \to (\bot \lor \bot) \\
&= \bot \to \bot \\
&= \top. \\
\end{align}$$